# how to check the x axis label in vba (Excel 2010)

Tags: vba, charts

This piece of code is trying to change the colour of the chart bars according to the Quarter (four quarters of a year and the same colour for every other quarter)

so my x-axis label is by month and I am trying to search for it and then use the Month() function to get the month number.

```
Sub chartcolour()
    Dim c As Chart
    Dim s As Series
    Dim iPoint As Long
    Dim nPoint As Long

    WSChart1.Activate
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate

   Set c = WSChart1.ChartObjects("Chart 3")

    Set s = c.SeriesCollection(1)

    nPoint = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count


    For iPoint = 1 To nPoint
        If Month(s.XValues(iPoint)) = 11 Or 12 Or 1 Then
            s.Points(iPoint).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 153, 255)
        ElseIf Month(s.XValues(iPoint)) = 2 Or 3 Or 4 Then
            s.Points(iPoint).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 51, 102)
        ElseIf Month(s.XValues(iPoint)) = 5 Or 6 Or 7 Then
            s.Points(iPoint).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 153, 255)
        Else
            s.Points(iPoint).Interior.Color = RGB(153, 51, 102)

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you elaborate 'by month'? Is it a date formatted as months, or is it text, or are they numbers (month-numbers), etc.?

Comment: The format is Mar-13 , Apr-13, etc. (In excel, the real value is 3/1/2013)

Comment: And what is the error you're encountering?

Comment: The Dim c as chartobject and s as series seems not working for excel 2010.  
 
Set c = WSChart1.ChartObjects("Chart 3") 
These two lines always show data type mismatch
    
Set s = c.SeriesCollection(1)

Comment: You haven't defined WSChart1 anywhere

Comment: WSChart1 is the worksheet name

Comment: WSChart1 is the name of the variable which is set to the worksheet? or is it the name of the worksheet itself?

Comment: It's the name itof worksheet itself

Comment: Sorry I may misunderstand you. It's the name I gave to the worksheet in the Macro Page not the Worksheet name on the worksheet tab

Comment: You'll need to post more information on the worksheet names, the rest of the code and show exactly which line is giving you the error, etc.

Comment: This is the full piece of code. The error is data type mismatch for the set c and set s statments

Comment: also I cannot debug the xvalue(ipoint) part, it will return me 438 error. So I donno what error exactly is that.

Comment: Set s = c.SeriesCollection(1) this line got error 438. (after replace wschart1 to activesheet

Comment: I also dim s as chartobject instead of chart. (not sure if it effects anything)

Answer (score 1):

For some reason you can't loop through the xvalues property because it's not a collection (you get an Error 451). See the code at the link below on how to work around it with an array variable.

[how to loop through xvalues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33138867/5446655)

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because "WSChart1" is the not clearly declared. Replace it with

```
ActiveSheet
```

and the code is likely to work as expected.